# Remove html/text from RSS feed description except images

Tags: html, regex, wordpress, rss

I am setting up a blog with WordPress, that uses a plugin to import RSS feeds and automatically publish them to the blog, on a schedule.

I only want to pull the images from the descriptions, not the text that sometimes appears with them, or other html elements.

There could be multiple images in a post, each one with captions, or links.

Ideally I'd like to use Yahoo Pipes to grab the feed, then use regex operator to replace everything with blank except `<img>` elements. Then send the manipulated feed to the WP plugin.

I've only managed to strip paragraphs so far, using: `<p>.*?</p>`. But in some cases there is plain text not wrapped in tags, etc.

Any help appreciated :) I'm a bit of a regex newbie.

Comment: Would [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with this to get all images from html code.

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$html, $allimages); 
print_r($allimages);
```

if you want image to be stored in string format then `implode` it with `,`

Comment: Thanks. I grabbed the RSS feed with PHP, then looped through the items with preg_match to find images, then outputted the file as RSS with new title and description fields containing only the images (with htmlspecialchars).